# Sql Join and Sum

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to sum an amount from two different tables using a left join.  I need all rows returned regardless of whether or not there is a match on the second table.

```
   SELECT l.tender, 
          l.starting+SUM(t.amount) AS 'amount' 
     FROM label l 
LEFT JOIN transfers t on l.tender=t.name 
 ORDER BY l.tender
```

Comment: @AD.Net hm, can you clarify what your comment means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT  l.tender, 
        l.starting + ISNULL(t.amount,0) AS amount
FROM label l 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT name, SUM(amount) amount
            FROM transfers
            GROUP BY name) t 
    ON l.tender = t.name 
ORDER BY l.tender
```

Comment: SUM(t.amount) in main query is unnecessary, just use t.amount.

Comment: @1010 you are completely right. It's not only unnecesary, but it also would throw a syntax error. Thanks, updated my answer now

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `SUM(amount)` in a `COALESCE` function so that if there is no match and it is `NULL`, it will add `0` and won't mark the whole row as `NULL`.

Change line 2 of your query to look like this:

```
      l.starting + COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS amount
```

Edit:

As @Lamak noted, you also need to `GROUP BY` your results so that you can `SUM` it properly. The whole query can look like this (alternative to the other answer):

```
   SELECT l.tender, 
          l.starting + COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS amount 
     FROM label l 
LEFT JOIN transfers t on l.tender=t.name 
GROUP BY l.tender, l.starting
ORDER BY l.tender
```

Comment: This isn't enough since there's no `GROUP BY`

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that, but his question did not have a `GROUP BY` either so it is not necessarily needed if the data uses a one-to-one relationship...

Comment: It is needed since it's doing a `SUM` with another column that's not wrapped in an aggregated column

Comment: And also, for the logic of the first query, it is actually necessary to join with the grouped value, otherwise the `l.starting + SUM(t.amount)` wouldn't make sense

Comment: Oops, you're right. Time for lunch and some fresh air, it seems. Thanks for the catch, I will edit my answer.

Comment: +1. Technically, the group by should be: `GROUP BY l.PK, l.tender, l.starting` where `PK` is the primary key of `label`.